# Repetir 2 veces cada caracter de una palabra

Tags: caracteres

Se que parece muy simple, quizas lo sea.-

Tengo un string con la palbra "Hola" y necesito que me decuelva la palabra con cada caracter retepito dos veces. Ejemplo.- "Hhoollaa"

Probe con repeat
con split
for each,

Comment: Comparte el código de tu intento, gracias !

Comment: Que lenguaje es esto? Que intento has hecho?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar un ciclo `for` que recorra cada carácter del `String` de entrada y cree un nuevo `String` de salida guardando cada carácter dos veces.

Código en Python:

```
def duplicar_caracteres(entrada):
string_duplicado = ''
for caracter in entrada:
    string_duplicado = string_duplicado + caracter + caracter 
return string_duplicado

print(duplicar_caracteres('Hola'))
```

Ten en cuenta que el resultado va a ser "HHoollaa".